# Finding relation between Torque and rate of change of Angular momentum , different approaches are giving different results

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, inertial-frames, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

All the vectors here are measured in the inertial frame of reference $I$ .

Notation used : $O$(origin) is a fixed point in $I$ . $C$ is the center of mass of the rigid body that I am considering and $m$ is its mass.

$\mathbf{r_{CA}}$ is the position vector of point $C$ with respect to point A.

$\mathbf{v_{C/O}}$ is velocity of point $C$ with respect to point $O$.

$\mathbf{a_{A/I}}$ is acceleration of point $A$ with respect to the frame $I$.

$\mathbf{H_{A/I}}$ is the angular momentum of the rigid body about the point $A$ with respect to the frame $I$.

$\mathbf{\tau_A}$ is the net torque on the rigid body about point $A$.

Now , I have come across two expression relating torque and rate of change of angular momentum . The expressions are :

1. $\mathbf{\tau_A = \dot H_{A/I} + r_{CA} \times ma_{A/I}}$
2. $\mathbf{\tau_A = \dot H_{A/I} + v_{A/O} \times mv_{C/I}}$

The first one is intuitive to me , as I can think of it as taking moment of a pseudo force on the rigid body because $A$ is accelerating with acceleration $\mathbf{a_{A/I}}$.

Here is the proof of the second one : https://youtu.be/NHedXxUO-Bg?list=PLUl4u3cNGP62esZEwffjMAsEMW_YArxYC&t=2161 ($36:02$ to $50:22$)

The second one is not intuitive to me but its proof seems completely correct to me. But clearly the above two expression will lead to different results but both seem correct to me. And I can't figure out what I am understanding wrong or missing.

Could someone please help me catch my mistake ?

Thanks !

Comment: The second equation is wrong $r_{CA}=r_{C}-r_{A}=$const. , thus the velocity $v_{CA}=0$ or $v_{C}=v_{A}$

Comment: why would it be zero ? $C$  can be moving as the rigid body can be moving and the point $A$ can also be moving.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

the torque about the center of mass is:

$$\vec \tau_{CM}=\vec u\times \vec F(t)\tag 1$$

where $~F(t)~$ is external force and  $~\vec F(t)=c\,\vec a_A(t)~$, where $\vec a_A$ is given  acceleration at point A,  you obtain (c is not the rigid body mass is just unit constant [kg])

$$\vec \tau_{CM}=\vec u\times  c\,\vec a_A(t)$$

if you have a given linear impulse $\vec p_A=c\,\vec v_A(t)~$ an point A, the momentum $\vec L_{CM}~$ is equal  $~\vec u\times \vec p_A$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec \tau_{CM}=\frac{d}{dt}\vec L=\vec u\times \vec c\,\frac {d}{dt}\vec v_A\tag 2$$

thus Eq.(2) is equal to Eq. (1)

notice  that in both case the body can only rotate about the center of mass with out translation and $\vec u$ is in body fixed coordinate system

Comment: In your answer , the first equation is definition of torque , and in the second equation , you have just replaced force by rate of change of linear momentum(which is the definition of force) , and so they are the same thing. But in my question , the two equation are different. In my question , according to the first equation if $\mathbf{a_{A/I}}$ is zero , then it wouldn't matter even if $\mathbf{v_{A/O}}$ is non-zero. But according to the second equation , the result will depend on the value of $\mathbf{v_{A/O}}$. So they don't seem to give the same result , but I can't find mistake in either

Comment: also , shouldn't we apply chain rule while differentiation $\mathbf{L}$ in equation $(2)$ , as $A$ does not necessarily lie on the rigid body , and can move independently.

Comment: So , this does not quite answer my doubt , but thanks a lot for your time. By the way , do you know why my question has been closed , I don't think that it is a "Homework" or "Check my work" type question. It is my doubt in my opinion :(